# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Hello my static method works when i call it first time but when i call it more than once its giving me strange error. Please help me in resolving this error

**My Method**

```
 public static void XVD(String string){
        String youtubeLink = "https://www.website.com/data?v="+string;
        new DataExtractor(MainActivity.context) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {


                }
            }
        }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);

    }
```

**Error (on second call to above method)**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No one knows MainActivity.context and DataExtractor is. But as a common bad pattern, static Context (MainActivity.context) is a reason. Null pointer will happen if it is null.